# How to debug VBScript in VS 2010 Professional?

Tags: vbscript

I have a VBScript file that on running from a SQL job is complaining about syntax error. I want to debug the file. I m sure there must be a way to debug it from vs 2010.  Can someone help me on that?
I tried to add a makeafile project but i didn't find vbscript file to add to makeafile project. Thanks.

Comment: Syntax errors cannot be "debugged" because the file won't even compile. Doesn't the error message say on which line there's an error?

Comment: I followed the link http://krgreenlee.blogspot.com/2006/04/excel-running-excel-on-windows-task.html and replaced example workbook and macro with my names. I did it in notepad. While running it from cmd, it says at lines 38 and 67. I don't know how to go to those lines and correct syntax. Any idea?

Comment: If you don't know how to go to a certain line in a text file, nobody here can help you.

Comment: My apologies. I corrected my sntax errors. I could run it w/o any errors. But it didn't refresh my excel file- which is the task it is supposed to do. So I want to step into the code line by line and see how/where it does that. Any idea? Thanks again.

Comment: Have you tried http://geekswithblogs.net/SoftwareDoneRight/archive/2008/04/14/quicktip-debugging-vbs-files-with-cscript.exe-and-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: Thanks Tomalak. It worked. i could step into my vbs code now.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice when using SQL in any language is to first assemble the query as a string, log this string and if the code fails you pick up the suspected query and run it interactive in a tool where you get proper SQL errors and can easily adjust the query until right. Then modify your code to get this query and you are done. I work with Oracle and there the tool is Sql*Plus.

```
sql = "select * from table where id=" & id
log(sql) 'a routine for logging you have to provide, in vbscript you could just wscript.echo
oConn.execute(sql) 'you get your error here
```